# Proof of $e^x (\ln x+\frac{1}{x})>\ln 8$

Tags: inequality

Prove that 
$$e^x \left(\ln x+\frac{1}{x}\right)>\ln 8$$

I found that the minimum of $e^x \left(\ln x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is close to $\ln 8$, then how do we prove that it's greater than $\ln 8$?

Comment: How did you obtain the minimum of that function?

Comment: If you did the standard study of a function by calculating its derivatives, you can obtain the minimum of that function and compare that value to $\ln 8$.

Comment: @Wyllich But studying the derivatives leaves you with $2x-1+x^2\ln x=0$, and I don't think that has a closed form solution.

Comment: @5xum You are indeed correct. Thinking...

Comment: @Wyllich It seems that near it's minimum, the function gets really close to $\ln 8$, but not all the way there: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5Ex(ln+x+%2B+1%2Fx)-+ln(8)+on+%5B0.5,+0.7%5D

Comment: @5xum Yes. I used wolfram too. I couldn't figure out if $ \ln 8$ is some arbitrary constant close to the minimum or a geometric feature...

Comment: $\ln8$ is not even that close to the minimum.
For example, 
$7^{\sin(\pi/8)}$ or $\sqrt{\ln(3\sqrt{3}-1)+3}$
are much closer.

Comment: @g.kov of course there are infinite many numbers that are closer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(x)=e^x \left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\log x\right)$

$f'(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^2} \left(x^2 \log x+2 x-1\right)$

$f'(x)=0\to x^2 \log x+2 x-1=0\to x\approx 0.59$

Taylor polynomial at $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$f(x)=\sqrt e \left[x^2 \left(5 -\dfrac{1}{8}  \log 16\right)+x \left(-5 -\dfrac{1}{8}  \log 16\right)+\dfrac{13 }{4}-\dfrac{1}{8}  \log 32\right]+O(x^3)$

$f(x)\approx 7.6722 x^2-8.81501 x+4.64409$ in a neighbourhood of $x=\frac12$

To estimate the error we need the third derivative

$f^{(3)}(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^4} \left(x^4 \log (x)+4 x^3-6 x^2+8 x-6\right)$

On the interval $[0.4,0.6]$ we have $|f^{(3)}(x)|\le 36.0234$

thus the error is $R_3(x)\le \dfrac{ |f^{(3)}(x)| \cdot \left|\,x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right|}{3!}\approx 0.006$

Now as 
$7.6722 x^2-8.81501 x+4.64409>\log 8;\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

we can conclude that $f(x)>\log 8$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Hope this helps

***Edit***

A graph can explain better. Remember that the minimum is at $x\approx 0.59$

[image]

Comment: without an estimation of the size of the O(x^3) term of the taylor polynom this is not a complete proof.

Comment: @miracle173 I wrote it in the answer "Error is less than 0.01 in absolute value"

Comment: but how did you derive this number?

Comment: @miracle173 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: I know, but I think an appropriate estimation for an appropriate interval should be part of the proof

Comment: @miracle173 Thank you for helping me to improve my proof

Comment: I can't see why $|f^{(3)}(x)|\le 36.0234$ nor why $7.6722 x^2-8.81501 x+4.64409>\log 8;\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. I think you didn't proof this.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the inequality as
$$f(x) = \ln(x) + \frac{1}{x} > \frac{\ln8}{e^x}=g(x).$$
$$f(x) > g(x)$$
The derivatives are:
$$f'(x) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{x-1}{x^2},$$
$$g'(x) = \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x} = -\frac{\ln8}{e^{x}}<0. $$
Clearly, $f'(x)$ is negative for $x\in [0,1)$ and positive for $x\geq 1$. It is easy to verify that $f(x)$ obtains its minimum at $x=1$, which is equal to $f(1)=1$.

Observe that $g(x=1) = \frac{\ln 8 }{e} <1$, which means that for $x \geq 1$, it is clearly $f(x) > g(x)$.

Now, for $x \in [0,1)$, first observe that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\ln(x) + \frac{1}{x}\right) = \infty,$$

which follows from the fact that, as $x$ decreases from $1$ to $0$, the rate of decrease of the first term is lower than the rate of increase of the second term.  Also observe that
$$\lim_{x \to 0}  g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln 8}{e^x} = \ln 8 < \infty.$$

This means that if $g(x)>f(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$ (where $0<a\leq b<1$), then $g'(x)=f'(x)$ for some $x\in[a,b]$.  Suppose this is the case, then $g'(x)=f'(x)$ means

$$\frac{1-x}{x^2} = \frac{\ln 8}{e^x}.$$

Note that if there is a solution to the above equation, this solution is unique as the RHS is increasing in $x$ while the LHS is decreasing in $x$ (it easy to verify).  Denote the solution by $x^*.$  This in its turn implies that the following must be true:

$$\ln(x^*) + \frac{1}{x^*} < \frac{\ln8}{e^{x^*}} = \frac{1-x^*}{(x^*)^2},$$

which means that $f(x^*)<-f'(x^*)$. For this inequality to be satisfied, we know that $-f'(x^*) >1$, or 
\begin{equation}
x<\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \tag{eq.1}
\end{equation}
However, notice that at $x=2/3 (>\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})$, we have
$$-f'(x) <- g'(x)$$
which implies that $x^*$ must be greater than $2/3$, which contradicts to (eq.1).

Answer (score 0):

$x>0$ : $\enspace\displaystyle e^{-x}x\ln 8 < 0.39+\frac{x}{2} < 1 + x\ln x$

---

Claim:  $\enspace\displaystyle e^x (\ln x + \frac{1}{x}) > \ln 8 \,$  or equivalent  $\,\displaystyle e^{-x}x\ln 8 < 1+x\ln x \,$  for $\,x>0\,$

We are looking for $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$  with: 
$\,\text{(A)}$ $\enspace\displaystyle e^{-x}x\ln 8 \leq a+\frac{x}{2}\enspace$ and $\,\text{(B)}$ $\enspace\displaystyle b+\frac{x}{2} \leq 1+x\ln x \,$

$\text{(A)}$ $\,$ Be $\,W(x)\,$ the main branch of the Lambert W-function: $\,W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$ with $\,\displaystyle x>-\frac{1}{e}$

Minimum of $\,\displaystyle  a+\frac{x}{2} - e^{-x}x\ln 8\,$ :

$\displaystyle  (a+\frac{x}{2} - e^{-x}x\ln 8)’=\frac{1}{2}+(x-1) e^{-x}\ln 8 := 0\,$ or equivalent $\,\displaystyle  (1-x)e^{1-x}=\frac{e}{2\ln 8}$

=> $\enspace\displaystyle x=1-W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8}) $

It follows the minimum with

$\displaystyle (a+\frac{x}{2} - e^{-x}x\ln 8)’’|_{ x=1-W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8}) }=\frac{1}{2}(1+1/ W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8}))\approx 1.672… > 0$

and the calculation of $\,a\,$ with

$\displaystyle (a+\frac{x}{2} - e^{-x}x\ln 8)|_{ x=1-W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8})}=a+1-\frac{x}{2}( W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8})+1/W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8}))\geq 0$

which gives the $a$-minimum value

$\displaystyle a:= -1+\frac{1}{2}( W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8})+1/W(\frac{e}{2\ln 8}))\approx 0.385317…<0.39\,$ .

$\text{(B)}$ $\,$ Same way as before, but much easier.

Minimum of $\,\displaystyle 1-b+x\ln x-\frac{x}{2} \,$ :

$\displaystyle  (1-b+x\ln x-\frac{x}{2})’=\frac{1}{2}+\ln x := 0\enspace$ => $\enspace\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$

It follows the minimum with $\enspace\displaystyle (1-b+x\ln x-\frac{x}{2})’’|_{ x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} }=\sqrt{e}>0 $

and the calculation of $\,b\,$ with 
$\enspace\displaystyle (1-b+x\ln x-\frac{x}{2})|_{ x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} }=1-b-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\geq 0$

which gives the $b$-maximum value $\,\displaystyle b:= 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\approx 0.393469…>0.39\,$ .

Result: $\,$ The claim is correct since $\enspace\displaystyle e^{-x}x\ln 8 < 0.39+\frac{x}{2} < 1 + x\ln x \,$ for $\,x>0\,$ .

Answer (score 0):

The function 
$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x}(x\log x+1)-\log 8$$
is defined for $x >0$ and we want to show that 
$$f(x)>0, \forall x >0.$$

We want to prove this and the proof will involve floating point calculations. Nevertheless the proof should be logically correct.

---

The expressions we calculate  are composed  of constants, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, powers and evaluation of elementary transzendental functions (exp, log).

If $\text{expr}$ is such an arithmetic expression then we write $\#[\text{expr}]$ for the numerical value calculated. In the table below the values have a precision of three digits after the decimal point.  This means that $|\text{expr} - \overline{\text{expr}}|<\delta_0,$ where $\delta_0=0.0005$.

$$
\begin{array}{ r | r | r |l|r }
  \text{line} & x, x_1& x_2&\text{expr}  & \#[\text{expr}] \\
 \hline
  1&&&-2e^{-\frac{3}{2}}+2& 1.554\\
 \hline
  2&0.591&&x^2 \log x+2x-1& -0.002\\
  3&0.593&&x^2 \log x+2x-1& 0.002\\
  4&0.591&0.593& {e^{x_1}}\left(\log x_1+\dfrac{1}{x_2}\right)-\log 8&0.016\\
  5&0.591&0.593&{e^{x_1}}\left(\log x_1+\dfrac{1}{x_1}\right)-\log 8 +\\
  &&&\qquad{e^{x_1}}\left( \log x_1 +\dfrac{2}{x_1}-\dfrac{1}{x_1^2}\right)(x_2-x_1)&0.026\\
\end{array}
$$

---

We plot  $f$ in a subinterval:

[image: graph of f]

$f$ seems to be a convex function with a global minimum at $x_0 \approx 0.6.$

If so, the first derivative $f’$ then must be an increasing function with a zero at $x_0,$ and the second derivative  $f’’$  must be a positive function.

$$f'(x)=\frac{e^x}{x^2}(x^2 \log x +2x-1)$$
$f’$ has a zero at $x_0.$

[image: graph of 1st derivative of f]

---

The proof that $f(x)>0,\; \forall x>0,$ consists of two steps:

1. prove that $f$ has a global minimum at $x_0$
2. prove that $f(x_0)>0$

The first step is more or less identical to the calculations in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2406478/11206). We repeat it here for the sake of completeness.

We have
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^x}{x^2}h(x)$$
where
$$\begin{eqnarray}
h(x)&=&x^2 \log x+2x-1\\
h'(x)&=&2x \log x+x+2\\ 
h''(x)&=&2\log x+3
\end{eqnarray}$$

We want to show that 
$$h'(x)>0, \; x>0$$
This is a problem similar to our original problem.

$h''$ is an increasing function with a zero at $e^{-\frac{3}{2}}$, so $h'$ has a global minimum at 
$e^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ and

$$h’(e^{-\frac{3}{2}}) =-2e^{-\frac{3}{2}}+2 \ge \#[-2e^{-\frac{3}{2}}+2] - \delta_0    \ge1.5535 >0, \tag{1}$$

Therefore $h$ is an increasing function and we have
$$h(0.591)\le \#[h(0.591)]+\delta_0<0<\#[h(0.593)]-\delta_0<h(0.593)$$

Because $h$ is increasing it has exactly one root $x_0$ and this is in $(0.591, 0.592)$

So we have 
$$h(x)
\begin{cases} 
<0, \;0<x< x_0\\ 
=0,\; x=x_0 \\
>0,\;x>x_0
 \end{cases}$$
and $x_0 \in (0.591, 0.592)$.
The same is true for $f’$ because it is a positive multiple of $h$ and so $f$ has a global minimum at $x_0$. This completes the first part of our proof.

Now we have to prove that $f(x_0)>0$ for this $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2)$.
It does not help to plug in the approximation into the function but we can do the following estimation:

$$\begin{array}\\ \tag{2}
f(x_0)&=&e^{x_0}(\log x_0+\dfrac{1}{x_0})-\log 8\\
&\gt& e^{x_1}(\log x_1+\frac{1}{x_2})-\log 8\\
&\ge& \#[e^{x_1}(\log x_1+\frac{1}{x_2})-\log 8]-\delta_0\\
&=&0.0155\\
&>&0
\end{array}$$

Or we can use the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

$$\exists \xi \in (x_1, x_0):\; \frac{f(x_0)-f(x_1)}{x_0-x1}=f'(\xi)$$

and therefore ($f'$ increasing, $f'(x_1)<0$)
$$\begin{array}\\ \tag{3}
f(x_0)&=&f(x1)+f’(\xi)(x_0-x_1)\\
&\ge& f(x1)+f’(x_1)(x_2-x_1) \\
&=&{e^{x_1}}\left(\log x_1+\dfrac{1}{x_2}\right)-\log 8 +{e^{x_1}}\left( \log x_1 +\dfrac{2}{x_1}-\dfrac{1}{x_1^2}\right)(x_2-x_1)\\
&\ge& \#[{e^{x_1}}\left(\log x_1+\dfrac{1}{x_2}\right)-\log 8 +{e^{x_1}}\left( \log x_1 +\dfrac{2}{x_1}-\dfrac{1}{x_1^2}\right)(x_2-x_1)]-\delta_0\\
&=&0.0255\\
&>&0
\end{array}$$

Answer (score -1):

I got a new way to calculate the minimum value.
Let
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&e^x(\ln x+\frac{1}{x})\\
f'(x)&=&\frac{e^x}{x^2}h(x)\\
h(x)&=&x^2 \ln x+2x-1\\
h'(x)&=&2x \ln x+x+2\\ 
h''(x)&=&2\ln x+3
\end{eqnarray}$$

- $h^{"}(x)$ has a zero point at $x=e^{-\frac{3}{2}}$,
- when $x>e^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ , $h^{"}(x)>0$,
- when $x<e^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ , $h^{"}(x)<0$

Therefore $h^{'}(x)>h^{'}(e^{-\frac{3}{2}})>0$
and $h(x)$ is increasing for $x>0$.

$h(1/e)<0$  and $h(0.594)=0.00421621...>0$ 
therefore exist $x_0 \in(1/e,0.594)$ such that $h(x_0)=0$, so
\begin{equation}
x_0^2\ln x_0+2x_0-1=0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

$h(x)$ is increasing on $x>0$
$$\begin{cases} h(x)<0,x\in(0, x_0)\\ h(x)>0,x\in(x_0,+\infty) \tag{2} \end{cases}$$
Then we have
$$\begin{cases} f^{'}(x)<0,x\in(0,x_0)\\ f^{'}(x)>0,x\in(x_0,+\infty) \tag{3} \end{cases}$$
thus
$$\min f(x)=f(x_0)=e^{x_0}(\ln x_0+\frac{1}{x_0})$$
from equation $(1)$ we have $\min f(x)=e^{x_0}\frac{1-x_0}{x_0^2}$

Let 
$$g(x)=e^x \frac{1-x}{x^2}$$
then $g^{'}(x)<0$ for $x>0$.
Because $x_0 \in (1/e,0.594)$
we have 
$$g(x_0)>g(0.594)=2.08413...>\ln 8.$$
and further
$$\min f(x)>\ln 8$$

Q.E.D

Comment: why does (2) hold?

Comment: you write "it' easy to prove that h(x) is increasing for x>0". I also think that h is increasing, but how do you prove it?

Comment: @miracle173 you can try to proof it, it's trivial.

Comment: You already wrote that it is trivial and of course I alread tried it but I didn't find a trivial proof. So would you be so nice to sketch your prove?

Comment: @miracle173 fine, added some details